# How to list users which belongs to specific group in ldap without backlink enabled

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldap-query

What is the search filter to list users belong to specific group like "engineering" in a ldap server which don't have backlink enabled.

For example, if backlink enabled i can use following filter,

```
(&(objectClass=person)(memberOf=cn=engineering,ou=Groups,o=company,o=com))
```

Wanted to know corresponding search query without using memberOf attribute.

Thanks
DarRay

Answer (score 1):

Try your filter as:

```
(&(objectClass=group)(cn=engineering))
```

using a base of

```
ou=Groups,o=company,o=com
```

and a scope of subtree
Returning attribute "member"

**Or even more efficient:**

```
(objectClass=group)
```

With a base of

```
cn=engineering,ou=Groups,o=company,o=com
```

and a scope of base
Returning attribute "member"

-jim

Answer (score 0):

The main question is: *How are the users linked to groups*?

One way is by specifying the users as attributes in the group. That can be done either via the `uniqueMember`- or the `memberUid`-Attribute. To find the users of a certain group you will have to use two queries. One query will retrieve the DNs or UIDs of the users of a group by fetching the `uniqueMember` or `memberUid` attribute of the group in question depending on your setup. Then you can retrieve the users by either using `(&(objectclass=person)(uid=<uid>))` or `(&(objectclass=person)(dn=<dn>))`.

The other way is by storing the grous as attributes in the user, which you described above.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The first query gives you the user DNs. That's all you should need.

Comment: You are of course right. The second query is only needed to get the user objects if you need them.